# Install Realtek USB driver 0bda:f179 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, usb, realtek-wireless, adapter

I just bought USB Wireless Adapter but didn't know how to install it.
I've tried using `lsusb` and `lshw -C Network` before and after plug the USB.

Here's the output of `lsusb`.

**Before:**

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:0543 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**After:**

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:0543 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 031: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It seems the difference is `Bus 003 Device 031: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.` But the output of `lshw -C Network` is same.

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: 01
       serial: b8:76:3f:bc:1d:ef
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:90700000-90707fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0e:00.0
       logical name: enp14s0
       version: 0c
       serial: 3c:07:71:59:b9:8a
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.100.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:27 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:90500000-90500fff memory:90400000-90403fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Should I install realtek wireless driver? If so, how to check which realtek wireless driver I should install?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the manufacturers name and model for this dongle?

Comment: Realtek f179 I suppose

Comment: Seems that this is the rtl8188ftv chipset and not supported in Linux

Comment: That is so sad :(