# Can't seem to get a Realtek USB WiFi adapter to work

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, 18.04, realtek-wireless

I feel like I've literally tried everything with this one.

**lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

**lsusb -t**

```
Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 480M
 |__ Port 3: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
 |__ Port 4: Dev 45, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=rndis_host, 480M
 |__ Port 4: Dev 45, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
 |__ Port 4: Dev 45, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=rndis_host, 480M
 |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
 |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
 |__ Port 6: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
 |__ Port 6: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
```

**nmcli device**

```
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION 
br-c90a12778d6e  bridge    connected    br-c90a12778d6e 
docker0          bridge    connected    docker0         
enp2s0           ethernet  unavailable  --              
lo               loopback  unmanaged    --
```

**lshw -class network**

```
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 15
   serial: 4c:cc:6a:93:b4:88
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:df004000-df004fff memory:df000000-df003fff
*-network:0
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: br-c90a12778d6e
   serial: 02:42:f0:ad:98:06
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.18.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
*-network:1
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 3
   logical name: docker0
   serial: 02:42:8f:77:a6:ed
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=ye
```

**wireless-info:**

https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/L9oatjrs/embedded/js/#JavaScript

Using `ndiswrapper`, I've added the `netrtwlanu_Vista` driver, which appears to be accepted: (`device: present` - I tried others as well, which didn't seem to be accepted)...
... but nothing appears in the WiFi Settings and nothing appears in the Additional Drivers tab (I did select "Main server" as source).
Also, in various posts and methods I read stuff about blacklisting:
*I have no idea what to blacklist and how to check if what's supposed to be blacklisted is.*

Before I buy a different WiFi USB dongle, I want to make sure there's nothing I can do about installing this one (I tested it and works on Windows 10).

Also, is there a list of USB WiFi devices that work on Ubuntu 18?

---

I'm far from being familiar with Ubuntu, please provide clear instructions. If more info is needed, let me know.

Comment: Please see my comments here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062402/cant-find-wifi-drivers-for-0bdaf179-realtek-semiconductor-corp?

Comment: @chili555. Thanks, that was what I was suspecting. But at least now I know it's not from my lack of linux knowledge. On a different note, is there a way to check whether a device has linux support before buying and trying? I plan on giving this one to the kids (they only use win) and buying another. but which?

Comment: There is a link (post #22) at the question I linked.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, the ([#22](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359573&page=3&p=13639455#post13639455)) is actually a direct link to it. Cheers!