# 0bda:f179 driver not working in ubuntu 19.10

Tags: iwlwifi

19.10 with  5.3.0-62-generic  ,0bda:f179
i tried rtl8188fu  for 0bda:f179 but
modprobe rtl8188fu stuck at nothing
also tried rtl8188eu but after that wifi sections shows  no wi-fi adapetr found
can someone help me

Comment: Did you try @champ's answer here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062402/cant-find-wifi-drivers-for-0bdaf179-realtek-semiconductor-corp  What, exactly, have you tried? How did it fail? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555  yes i tried every options  tried ppa & git clone  in both cases it was success & dkms status listed  rtl8188fu  1.0 with 5.3.0-62-generic  then i restarted network manager  but wifi section still shows no adapter  found  so i tried  plug-out and plugin adapter still no   and also system wont restart after that stucks in the booting anime  to  avoid that i cut the power supply then power on then removed rlt8188fu from dkms removed ppa