# unable to install wifi drivers from rtlwifi_new git repo

Tags: drivers, realtek-wireless, adapter

When I tried installing git from clone it's asking for username & password

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
Cloning into 'rtlwifi_new'...
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

please help

```
shdpjjc@shdpjjc-System-Product-Name:~$ rfkill list
shdpjjc@shdpjjc-System-Product-Name:~$ 
shdpjjc@shdpjjc-System-Product-Name:~$ 
shdpjjc@shdpjjc-System-Product-Name:~$ uname -a
Linux shdpjjc-System-Product-Name 4.13.0-36-generic #40~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 16 23:26:51 UTC 2018 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux
shdpjjc@shdpjjc-System-Product-Name:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3;
```

below command gives blank

```
rfkill list 
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
```

```
Below solution resolved my problem

I was able to resolve the issue after following this post in https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062402/cant-find-wifi-drivers-for-0bdaf179-realtek-semiconductor-corp


The concern was we were using 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp which requires specific drivers.

Thanks Everyone for the Help :)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information. What OS you are using, what is your wireless device, why are you thinking you need Realtek drivers?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list; umane -a` terminal command.

Comment: Are you using a USB adapter? You don't have any PCI wireless devices. There is no reason to install `rtlwifi` at all. You didn't explain why you are trying to install it.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue after following this post in https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062402/cant-find-wifi-drivers-for-0bdaf179-realtek-semiconductor-corp


The concern was we were using 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp which requires specific drivers.

Thanks Everyone for the Help :)

Answer (score 0):

The `https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git` has been removed.

Use `https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git` instead.

To install them run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
sudo dkms add ./rtw88
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Comment: bash: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git: No such file or directory

Comment: What do you mean? You need to clone it.

Comment: i'm not tech savy this is an old desktop so thought of getting hand on linux

Comment: i tried this & the reply on terminal was ~/rtw88$ git checkout extended
error: pathspec 'extended' did not match any file(s) known to git

Comment: if you can help

Comment: Please add more information to your question. There is no `extended` branch there.

Comment: shdpjjc@shdpjjc-System-Product-Name:~$ git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
fatal: destination path 'rtw88' already exists and is not an empty directory.
shdpjjc@shdpjjc-System-Product-Name:~$ cd rtw88
shdpjjc@shdpjjc-System-Product-Name:~/rtw88$ git checkout extended
error: pathspec 'extended' did not match any file(s) known to git.
shdpjjc@shdpjjc-System-Product-Name:~/rtw88$

Comment: i'm using windows 7

Comment: Why would you need Linux drivers for Windows 7? PLEASE EDIT YOUR QUESTION and explain what are you doing. WHY are you running these commands? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i've installed ubuntu on windows 7

Comment: You can't install ubuntu on Windows 7. Please stop posting comments. I give up till you edit your question.

Comment: i've installed it & running on dual boot

Comment: okie if you want i'll edit my question but i've installed ubuntu 18.04 on windows 7

Comment: Anyone, please can help me here, still struggling.